# Changing font awesome icon onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome, show-hide

I'm trying to swap .fa-eye to fa-eye-slash when user click on a button. What am I doing wrong? It's not working.

HTML code:

```
<button onclick="arata_ascunde(this);" style="align:right;font-size:13px" 
class="btn btn-info " id="show_hide_bt" style="background-color:#00b0ff;"><i 
class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function arata_ascunde(button) {
     var x = document.getElementById('showhide');
     var change = document.getElementById("show_hide_bt");

     if (x.style.display === 'none') {
       x.style.display = 'block';
     } else {
       x.style.display = 'none';
     }

     if (change.innerHTML == ' Show')
            {

                change.innerHTML = ' Hide';
                $(button).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
            }
            else {

                change.innerHTML = ' Show';
                $(button).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye');
            }


  }
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` of `change` contains the markup of the <i> tag.  It will not match the string you are checking against.  You should check to see if the nested <i> tag has the `fa-eye` class or not, instead of evaluating against innerHTML.  And for future reference, if an `if` statement is not acting like you expect, try console.log'ing the values and see what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function arata_ascunde(button) {
   var x = $('#showhide');
   $(button).find('i').remove();
   if ($(button).text().trim() == 'Show') {
     $(button).html($('<i/>',{class:'fa fa-eye-slash'})).append(' Hide');
     x.fadeIn();
    }
    else {
      $(button).html($('<i/>',{class:'fa fa-eye'})).append(' Show');
      x.fadeOut();
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="arata_ascunde(this);" style="align:right;font-size:13px"
            class="btn btn-info " id="show_hide_bt" style="background-color:#00b0ff;">
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show
    </button>
    <div id="showhide" style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px;margin:10px;display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const icon = this.querySelector('i');
  const text = this.querySelector('span');

  if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye')) {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-eye');
    icon.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
    text.innerHTML = 'Hide';
  } else {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
    icon.classList.add('fa-eye');
    text.innerHTML = 'Show';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>Show</span></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have inserted Jquery. You can do this via Jquery easily.

```
<button style="align:right;font-size:13px" class="btn btn-info" id="show_hide_bt" style="background-color:#00b0ff;"><i 
class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</button>
```

Now Jquery code for this is

```
$("#show_hide_bt").click(function(event) {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
});
```

If you want to remove the fa-eye class then you can chain another toggleClass or add this again

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye');
```

Or add this in single line. Comment if this doesnot help

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash').toggleClass('fa-eye');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the results you want by simplifying your HTML and JQuery.

Try this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const button = $(".btn");

  button.click(() => {
    if (button.text() == " Show") {
      button.html('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide');
    } else {
      button.html('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class='btn btn-default'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</button>
```

You could toggle the class like so: `$('i').toggleClass("fa-eye-slash fa-eye");`, but since you want to change the text too, I would recommend the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-thumbs-down");
}
```

```css
.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Click on the icon to toggle between thumbs-up and thumbs-down (like/dislike):</p>
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```